# WinForms DataGridView and PropertyGrid behavior

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, propertygrid, browsable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a property visible in DataGridView but NOT in PropertyGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726543/make-a-property-visible-in-datagridview-but-not-in-propertygrid)

I am using both the DataGridView and PropertyGrid in an application and set it to a data source as follows:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Locations: List<Location> { }
```

In case of the DataGridView, the `Locations` object is set as a data source and in case of the PropertyGrid, a single `Location` object is set as the `SelectedObject`.

I need the `Status` variable to display in the DataGridView but not on the PropertyGrid. The default way to hide members is to mark them with the `[System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]` attribute but that makes it disappear from both views.

Is there another way to force `Status` to appear on the DataGridView?

Comment: maybe not the most elegant way, but this should work. protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
}

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12218046/316644)

Comment: @Haxx: Thanks. I agree. Not elegent but will work.

Comment: @digEmAll: Thank you! You should post this as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: since it has already been answered, I'm going to mark this one as duplicated of the other question. You should upvote that answer :)

Comment: @Haxx: that's a web gridview event. Here we're talking about winforms. Also, by doing that you're hiding the property in the gridview while OP wants to hide it in the property grid.

Comment: Ah sorry deleted the answer.